# Apache Ignite .Net Store ComplexType in Session

Tags: .net, serialization, ignite

I want to use apache ignite as a centralized session server.My problem is ignite cant store objects which have not serializable attribute.For example my object like that .But it cant serialize Person object because of  PersonDetail entity.Is some one can share use .net sample of ignite to use session without add every nested entity serializable attribute.

```
[Serializable]
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }

        public PersonDetail PDetail
        {
            get
            {
                return pDetail;
            }

            set
            {
                pDetail = value;
            }
        }

        private PersonDetail pDetail;

    }


    public class PersonDetail
    {

        private int Salary { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

My web config like...

```
 <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="IgniteSessionStateProvider">
          <providers>
            <add name="IgniteSessionStateProvider"
               type="Apache.Ignite.AspNet.IgniteSessionStateStoreProvider, Apache.Ignite.AspNet"
               igniteConfigurationSectionName="igniteConfiguration"
               applicationId="myUI"
               gridName="mysessiontest"
               cacheName="myWebCache" />
          </providers>
        </sessionState>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignite.NET uses `BinaryFormatter` to serialize session state data, so the requirement to have all the nested classes `[Serializable]` comes from there.

There is no Ignite-related workaround. You can serialize your data with a different serializer and put `byte[]` to the session state.

Comment: Do you have any senario like us?We have so many nested class and different items?We cant add each class to serializable attribute...

Comment: @Bilgehan Why not do what Pavel suggested? Just preserialize everything yourself and store a byte array in Ignite. This way you can handle all the serialization before you put anything into Ignite.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options:

1. As Pavel notes, you could [choose a different way to serialise the whole, nested structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52151397/2998)
2. Alternatively, you could choose [not to serialise the nested objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx)

I don't have a .net environment to test, but in theory this should work:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyObject 
{
  public int n1;
  [NonSerialized] public int n2;
  public String str;
}
```